# Aceitar carácter maiúsculo e minúsculo

Tags: c, if

Estou fazendo um rascunho só para treinar o `if` e o `else` que vai ser assunto na minha próxima aula na faculdade. Eu quero chegar lá e pelo menos já ter uma base do que o professor vai ensinar.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte.

Quando eu peço para o usuário digitar `s` (Sim) ou `n` (Não) para mostrar a tabuada funciona, porém se o usuário digitar o `S` em letra maiúscula a IDE executa o bloco do `else`.

Como que eu faço para o usuário só digitar letras maiúsculas no `printf`?

Segue o código abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){

  int num;
  char sn;
  printf("DESEJA ABRIR A TABUADA? S/N: ");
  scanf("%c", &sn);

  if(sn=='s') {
        printf("\nDIGITE O NUMERO DA TABUADA QUE DESEJA: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("\n%d x 1 = %d\n", num , num*1);
        printf("%d x 2 = %d\n", num , num*2);
        printf("%d x 3 = %d\n", num , num*3);
        printf("%d x 4 = %d\n", num , num*4);
        printf("%d x 5 = %d\n", num , num*5);
        printf("%d x 6 = %d\n", num , num*6);
        printf("%d x 7 = %d\n", num , num*7);
        printf("%d x 8 = %d\n", num , num*8);
        printf("%d x 9 = %d\n", num , num*9);
        printf("%d x 10 = %d\n\n", num , num*10); 
  }

  else
       printf("\nOK, PROGRAMA FINALIZADO.\n\n");

  system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Pode usar a função [**toupper**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_toupper.htm) e converter o `sn` para maiúsculo,
  depois coloca algo como :

  `if(sn=='S')`

*Deste modo, se o usuário escrever `s` vai converter para `S`, se escrever `S` mantém. Ou seja, desta forma tanto pode escrever em maiúscula ou minúscula.*

---

- Outra forma seria colocar o operador `||` (OU)

  `if(sn=='S' || sn=='s')// sn igual a S OU sn igual a s`

---

P.S. O usuário não vai  digitar no `printf`, o `scanf` é que lê o que o usuario escrever.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, consegui aqui.